# Oracle Left outer joining same tables multiple times

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have four tables named as `ROLE,EMPLOYEE, HIERARCHY_UNIT, EMPLOYEE_CLASS` all of them have a different nameid column which is a primary key to `STRING_TABLE` table.Also `STRING_TABLE` will have a column stringtext that stores the exact text or we can say name.

All of these tables are linked as all of them will have a empid column.

Now i want to select some information from `EMPLOYEE` table along with the names of corresponding role, hierarchy_unit,employeeclass.My select query willl be something like

```
SELECT EMPST.STRINGTEXT,EROLE.STRINGTEXT,EHIER.STRINGTEXT,EEMPCLASS.STRINGTEXT 
FROM EMPLOYEE EMP 
INNER JOIN ROLE RO ON ROLE.EMPID=EMP.EMPID
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE_CLASS EC ON EC.EMPID = EMP.EMPID
INNER JOIN HIERARCHY_UNIT HU ON HU.EMPID=EMP.EMPID
LEFT OUTER JOIN STRING_TABLE EMPST ON EMPST.NAMEID=EMP.NAMEID
LEFT OUTER JOIN STRING_TABLE EROLE ON RO.NAMEID=EROLE.NAMEID
LEFT OUTER JOIN STRING_TABLE EHIER ON HU.NAMEID=EHIER.NAMEID
LEFT OUTER JOIN STRING_TABLE EEMPCLASS ON EEMPCLASS.NAMEID=EC.NAMEID
```

The above query is working fine but i have  a question whether doing the join to same table will not cause any performance issue. In the above example i have taken left outer join 3 times ( in actual i have a case of 26 joins with the string table ).Is there any way to optimize the above select query n and not to take join with same table  multiple times?

Comment: from joins I see you're joining EMPLOYEE, ROLE, EMP_CLASS, and HIERARCHY by emp_id. For me that means, they all are going to have same nameid. Am I right?

Comment: No they'll all have there seperate nameid's  as they all have different names like role will  have nameid 1 that maps to string cashier , employee_class will have nameid 4 thay maps to string EC-1CLASS.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to say anything about performance of a query without it's execution plan. Guessing is the only thing possible at the moment.

So, assuming STRING_TABLE.NAMEID is worth indexing (there are many unique values) and you already have this column indexed, this query is fine.

In the select-part of the query you've specified 4 STRING_TABLE's columns. This means you're asking the database to find values for different NAMEIDs from 4 different lines in that table and post them in one line for each line  in the result query.

What the database has to do is looking 4 times (or 26 in production) for the particular line with particular nameid for each line in the output. This is why you need to join STRINGS_TABLE 4 times and, again, this is fine as long as column is worth-indexing and is already indexed.

If there are many non-unique data in NAMEID column, you might need to use partitioning or even to change database structure in order to get better performance. But, again, query is fine and I don't see any way to make it better